# How to check for level in react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a heading `<h4>Big offer!</h4>` on the page, when I first ran my tests I got:

```
Expected: "Big offer!"
Received: <h4>Big offer!</h4>

  35 |     const switchToggle = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
  36 |     expect(switchToggle.checked).toEqual(true);
> 37 |     expect(titleEl).toEqual(title);
```

Ok, it get's correct file, so I changed my code to actually check heading level and text, but it failed:

```
Expected: "Big offer!"
Received: undefined

  35 |     const switchToggle = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
  36 |     expect(switchToggle.checked).toEqual(true);
> 37 |     expect(titleEl.name).toEqual(title);
     |                          ^
  38 |     expect(titleEl.level).toEqual(4);
```

I always thought that `.name` is equal to `getByText()`. I commented out a line and tried checking for level, and it failed again:

```
Expected: 4
Received: undefined

  36 |     expect(switchToggle.checked).toEqual(true);
  37 |     //expect(titleEl.name).toEqual(title);
> 38 |     expect(titleEl.level).toEqual(4);
```

I don't understand why my test cases failed. Code for test was:

```
const title = 'Big offer!';
render(<Component title={title}/>);
const titleEl = screen.getByRole('heading');
expect(titleEl).toEqual(title);
expect(titleEl.level).toEqual(4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont work because `screen.getByRole` (or others querys) returns an `HTMLElement` (in your case returns a `HTMLHeadingElement` that inherits `HTMLElement`). And it doesnt have `name` or `level` properties. You can check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHeadingElement).

To check the text rendered you should use:

```js
expect(titleEl).toHaveTextContent(title);
```

And for `h4` type check you just need to filter it on query:

```
const titleEl = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 4 });
```

The full test:

```js
it('test search input', async () => {
    const title = 'Big offer!';

    render(<SearchBox title={title} />);

    const titleEl = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 4 });

    expect(titleEl).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(titleEl).toHaveTextContent(title);
});
```